# Connection refused on other side for simple protocol

Tags: twisted

My two dependent class methods develop a Protocol to define the connection strategy and a factory to open the connection. I have instigated a reactor to run this by connecting to a local host and a port, however I get the following error:

> Connection failed. Reason: [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError'>: Connection was refused by other side: 61: Connection refused.

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, task, reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import ClientFactory
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ClientEndpoint, connectProtocol

class TestClass(protocol.Protocol):

    def __init__(self):
        self._make_connection = self.transport.write("Connect to the transport")
        self.cnt_lost = self.transport.loseConnection()
        self._tst = self.transport.getPeer()
    
    def test_transport(self):
        self._make_connection
        self._tst
        self.cnt_lost

class EchoClientFactory(ClientFactory):
    def startedConnecting(self, connector):
        print('Started to connect.')

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        print('Connected.')
        return TestClass()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print('Lost connection.  Reason:', reason)

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print('Connection failed. Reason:', reason)
    
reactor.connectTCP('127.0.0.1', 8050, EchoClientFactory())
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not much of an answer, I managed to fix the issue above however I do not get any data returned from the server, for example, I should be getting:

```
Connect to the transport
```

Instead, I just get:

```
Connected
```

Neither, do I get the remote access of the connection.

Here's what I have tried:

listen in on the connection

```
class TestClass(protocol.Protocol):

    def recieved_data(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)
        

class readClientFactory(ClientFactory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        print('Connected.')
        return TestClass()

    
reactor.listenTCP(8070, readClientFactory())
reactor.run()
```

Connect to the port:

```
class readClass(protocol.Protocol):

    def connectionmade(self):
        self.transport.write(b"Connect to the transport")
        self.transport.getPeer()
    
    def test_transport(self):
        self.transport.loseConnection()

class readClientFactory(ClientFactory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        print('Connected.')
        return readClass()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print('Lost connection.  Reason:', reason)
        reactor.stop()

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print('Connection failed. Reason:', reason)
        reactor.stop()
    
reactor.connectTCP('127.0.0.1', 8070, readClientFactory())
reactor.run()
```

output:

```
Connected.
```

It should be:

```
Connected.
Connect to the transport
 --- Then some stuff about the ip
```